# How can one use publish_pages without a user access_token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, azure-web-app-service, kentico

I have a web app running Kentico v10.0.11 and want to enable content editors, (not facebook users), to save a page in the CMS that then causes a publish_page action on the Facebook page this website represents.

Specifically, users should navigate to the Pages module, select the Surf Conditions page, and check "Post to Facebook" in the Form tab to create a Facebook post when they save the page, (e.g., https://docs.kentico.com/k10/community-features/integrating-social-media/configuring-automatic-posting-to-social-media )

*[illustration of expected functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrM86.png)

Comment: Please include some code which you have tried. Follow this link for instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to allow non-logged in users to publish pages, or are some of your content editors not able to see the facebook page and that's the issue?  Trying to figure out what this has to do with the user access_token.  Thanks!

Comment: To post _as_ a page, you need a page access token.

Comment: Now i think i get you, you mean the FACEBOOK access_token.  I thought in Kentico you can save the Facebook access_token for those pages through the Facebook > Pages > (Edit page) > Authorize.  Have you tried that?  It may expire after X amount of time, but once someone does this everyone should be able to publish.

Comment: That's right @TrevorJFayas
It turns out the issue was with Kentico and not with Facebook after all.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with Kentico and not with Facebook. https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/why-can-t-kentico-authorize-facebook-page-access

The issue was resolved in Kentico Hotfix 10.0.31 https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes